# Encountered BSOD PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA after installed windows update KB4088875 (Windows 7 32 bit)

Tags: windows-7, bsod, 32-bit

Currently using Windows 7 without issue. After executing `Windows6.1-kb4088875-x86.msu` downloaded from Microsoft website, pc was restarted.

Upon restarting pc, the following BSOD screen was encountered.

[image: https://ibb.co/gxiR4x]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Image doesn’t work.  Use imgur instead

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2719594/0x00000050-stop-error-in-windows-7-or-in-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: @Ramhound The image worked for me. The full error code is 0x00000050 (0x80523110, 0x00000000, 0x8213B676, 0x00000000).

Comment: @MichaelBay - It works for me, but I have to disable my web filtering, the image should be hosted to SE's Imgur account anyways (takes zero effort on the user's part).

Comment: if you can boot to windows, [use Windbg to analyze](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) the [crash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

Answer (score -2):

Well, you know what caused it (bad install of update)

What is preventing you from rolling back to the restore point made immediately before the update?

If you have a crash dump accessible by going through safe mode / a live OS, you could do some specific analyzing if you really wanted to.